# Merge two divs and reorder

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have two divs with child elements, I wish to move the divs in div 2 into div 1. I can do this like this:

```
var divstoMove = $('.combineDivs .div2 div').detach();
$('.combineDivs .div1').append(divstoMove);
$('.combineDivs .div2').hide();
```

My question is how do I reorder the divs once they have been moved like this:

Current markup

```
<div class="combineDivs">

<div class="div1">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Desired markup

```
<div class="combineDivs>

<div class="div1">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
</div>
```

There could be any number of divs in each column

Comment: Can you post the current HTML and the desired new HTML?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version that works when the lists are of unequal length - get the list of divs from both containers, then merge them into the first container:

```js
var set1 = $('.combineDivs .div1 div').get();
var set2 = $('.combineDivs .div2 div').get();
var ctr = $('.combineDivs .div1');

for ( var i = 0; (i < set1.length) || (i < set2.length); ++i )
  {
    if (i < set1.length)
      ctr.append(set1[i]);
    if (i < set2.length)
      ctr.append(set2[i]);
  }

$('.combineDivs .div2').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combineDivs">

  <div class="div1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="div2">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Replaced the original with a simpler version that behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if there are the same number of child divs in both divs

```js
var divstoMove = $('.combineDivs .div2 div').detach();
$('.combineDivs .div1 div').each(function(i, el) {
  $(this).after(divstoMove.eq(i));
});
$('.combineDivs .div2').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combineDivs">
  <div class="div1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71712hqa/1/

And here is a more general solution that handles the case where there are different numbers of elements.

```js
var divstoMove = $('.combineDivs .div2 div').detach();
var $div1 = $('.combineDivs .div1');
var $div1Divs = $div1.find('div');
$div1Divs.each(function(i, el) {
  $(this).after(divstoMove.eq(i));
});

if (divstoMove.length > $div1Divs.length) {
  $div1.append(divstoMove.splice($div1Divs.length, divstoMove.length - $div1Divs.length))
}

$('.combineDivs .div2').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combineDivs">
  <div class="div1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71712hqa/3/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing real html, or knowing if there are are equal quantities, you could try using the index of the elements to do insertion matching

```js
    var $existDivs =  $('.combineDivs .div1').children();
    $('.combineDivs .div2').children().each(function(i){
        $(this).insertAfter($existDivs.eq(i));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combineDivs">

<div class="div1">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>

</div>
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dkgorLr/)